# Inline input and button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please, how can I inline a button and an input field without using `<form>`? I'm trying this way but it's not working.

```css
.inline-button .inline-input{
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <label for="contractNumID" class="sr-only">Contract Number</label>
      <input type="text" readonly id="contractNumID" class="form-control-plaintext" mid="staticContract" value="Contract Number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
      <label for="contractNumber" class="sr-only">Contract</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control inline-input" id="contractNumber"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 inline-button" data-inline="true">
      <button type="" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
        Populate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to inline all the fields and the button on one single line?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to inline all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `form` to a `div` and removed the additional CSS. I've also included the Bootstrap library because it appears that's what you're using.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="contractNumID" class="sr-only">Contract Number</label>
    <input type="text" readonly id="contractNumID" class="form-control-plaintext" mid="staticContract" value="Contract Number" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <label for="contractNumber" class="sr-only">Contract</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control inline-input" id="contractNumber" />
  </div>
  <button type="" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Populate</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```css
.col-md-2 > div {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <label for="contractNumID" class="sr-only">Contract Number</label>
      <input type="text" readonly id="contractNumID" class="form-control-plaintext" mid="staticContract" value="Contract Number"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
      <label for="contractNumber" class="sr-only">Contract</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control inline-input" id="contractNumber"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2 inline-button" data-inline="true">
      <button type="" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">
        Populate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you bother to try this before submitting? Also, look at the classes. These are bootstrap classes. No additional CSS is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the response Millhorn, as the title ask "Inline input and button". 
of course, bootstrap is used here according to the classes, but if it is not possible to add libraries and there is a desire to perform a task, it might be nice to have the option in to do it with CSS. (Bootstrap is CSS)